# 2 war files under same single tomcat - static resource sharing

Tags: java, tomcat, war

I have **2 wars deployed under single tomcat instance**.

Can i use **static resources (js/css)** of one war into another to avoid duplicay of the code. If yes how can i use them. Is giving the full path sufficient.

eg.

```
A.war

B.war
```

I want to use `sample.js` file from `A.war into B.war index.html`

Comment: Yes you can, but shutting down or undeploying one app will cause the other to break. Css and JavaScript files are very small, just deploy them twice.

Comment: @techprat i am not asking about java classes/methods, instead to access static resources

Comment: @Stefan Thanks, but to reduce duplicay of code , i do not want to have the same code at 2 places. Also if i can access static resources from another war, is it the path i need to set or something else as well.

Comment: It's totally possbile to do a library with static code, this way you avoid codeduplication and still have js and css in both wars. Look in particular  for wars overlays or webjars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. You simply need to put the context root of application A in the path for the script reference, e.g. like this

```
<script src="/A/sample.js"></script>
```